# JAXB don't marshal attribute

Tags: java, xml, attributes, tags, jaxb

I have some class generated by jaxb mave plugin like this:

```
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo", namespace = "urn://some-urn")
public class Foo {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id", required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
    protected BigInteger name;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "age", required = true)
    protected String age;
```

I need to marshal object from this class, but JAXB marshaling attributes as an elements.

Required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Foo xmlns:ns2="urn://some-urn" id="1" name="Boris" age="43">
    //some elements in the root element
</ns2:Foo>
```

Provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Foo xmlns:ns2="urn://some-urn">
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Boris</name>
    <age>43</age>
</ns2:Foo>
```

Marshalling method:

```
public String marshalToXml(Foo foo) {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            QName qName = new QName("urn://some-urn",
                    "Foo");
            JAXBElement<Foo> bar = new JAXBElement<>(qName, Foo.class, foo);
            marshaller.marshal(bar, stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.toString();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to marshal the object to xml?

Comment: @f1sh Updated
Forgot about it